# Grabbing the second line wrt a certain string and appending it to a new list

Tags: python, list

Here is a fragment of a file from which I want to extract only the names into a new list.

```
Name1 
Comment1
 · 
Reply
 · 1d
Name2
Comment2
 · 
Reply
 · 1d
Name3
Comment3
 · 
Reply
 · 1d
Name4
Comment4
 · 
Reply
 · 1d
Name5
Comment5
 · 
Reply
 · 1d
```

The idea is to grab the second line after 'Reply' and append it to a new list, how one would implement that in python?

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension:

```py
with open(r"file.txt") as file:
    string = file.read().splitlines()

lst = [string[index+2] for index, item in enumerate(string) if (item=='Reply' and index+2<len(string))]
# or lst = [string[index+2] for index in range(len(string)) if (string[index]=='Reply' and index+2<len(string))]
print(lst)
```